# Interpretation of Hosmer Lemeshow (goodness-of-fit) Test from rms package

Tags: logistic, interpretation, r-squared, auc, hosmer-lemeshow-test

I applied a Hosmer-Lemeshow-Test (now named only goodness-of-fit?) provided by the RMS Package by Prof. Harrel. The p-values for my model were not significant, therefor applying the following link:
[Goodness-of-fit test in Logistic regression; which 'fit' do we want to test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169000/goodness-of-fit-test-in-logistic-regression-which-fit-do-we-want-to-test)

I fail to reject the Null-Hypothesis, therefor I cannot reject the model if that is correct.

However while applying also a Pseudo-R² measure with extremly low levels (from a different package, but the one from the RMS-package suggest the same) aswell as plotting the ROC and calculating the AUC, I ask myself:
How to interpret the Hosmer-Lemeshow-Test?

Is it right to state: While it is not possible to reject the model, there is plenty of room for improving it? Can I state something like: Even though the model isn't significantly or logically false it doesn't represent the data appropiately? What statement can I really conduct from this outcome?

I am still a nooby in this platform, please don't pick on me again.

Comment: In this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35422/validation-of-logistic-regression-goodness-of-fit-pearson/35427#35427  it is stated that Hosmer-Lemeshow test is now considered obsolete

Comment: I know, but it is the replacement-test for Hosmer-Lemeshow which is now named goodness-of-fit test? The author of this test in rms package is the same author of this post, naming hosmer-lemeshow obsulete. does it mean the test is obsolete or does it mean also the new adoptions of it are obsolete.

Comment: I am sorry about the (old) downvote.  We cannot control voting; it's up to community members to decide which questions might need more research or clarification.  *I* think this is a well-formulated question, so I have upvoted it.  But I only get one vote... .

Comment: Package `rsm` does not compute the Hosmer-Lemeshow tests, but can compute some better tests. See functions (in `rsm`) `val.prob` and `residuals.lrm`.